# Unable to tunnel port using SSH and localhost.run on Kali Linux

Tags: ssh, kali-linux, ssh-tunnel, wan

I've got this problem that whenever I try to tunnel a Port using ssh and localhost.run using:-

`ssh -R 80:localhost:8080 ssh.localhost.run`

I get this:-

```
** your connection id is 95c80293-xxxx-4c49-8ec4-4xxxxxxxxxxx, please mention it if you send me a message about an issue. **

===============================================================================
Welcome to localhost.run!

Head over to https://twitter.com/localhost_run and give us a follow for the
hottest SSH port forwarded local dev env news.

**You need a SSH key to access this service.**

Github has a great howto, follow along with it to get prepared for the change:
https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

**CUSTOM DOMAINS ARE HERE AND I'M SO EXCITED**
I've been working hard on custom domains and I'm soft launching the custom
domain plan option to existing users. If you own a domain name that you'd like
localhost.run on visit https://admin.localhost.run/ to look at the plan
and set it up.

===============================================================================

Connect to http://root-e092f6aa.localhost.run
{"domain": "root-e092f6aa.localhost.run", "listen_port": 80, "status": "success", "message": "Connect to http://root-e092f6aa.localhost.run"}
```

But when I go to `http://root-e092f6aa.localhost.run` it says `Something went wrong opening the port forward, check your SSH command output for clues!`

And in the terminal it is written `connect_to localhost port 8080: failed.`

I also ran `ssh -vvv localhost`

It shows :-

```
OpenSSH_8.3p1 Debian-1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "localhost" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/kali/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kali/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kali/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kali/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kali/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kali/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kali/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kali/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kali/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kali/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kali/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kali/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kali/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/kali/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.3p1 Debian-1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.3p1 Debian-1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.3p1 Debian-1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'kali'
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:omteMgqLQrYTg6UmnCyNsT9FLa2gKrvGn0yj6XL0RiE
The authenticity of host 'localhost (::1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:omteMgqLQrYTg6UmnCyNsT9FLa2gKrvGn0yj6Xxxxxx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/kali/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/kali/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/kali/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/kali/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/kali/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/kali/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/kali/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/kali/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/kali/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/kali/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/kali/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/kali/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/kali/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/kali/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/kali/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/kali/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/kali/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/kali/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/kali/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/kali/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /home/kali/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
kali@localhost's password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to localhost ([::1]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IPV6_TCLASS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWID
debug3: Ignored env QT_ACCESSIBILITY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_PATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_MENU_PREFIX
debug3: Ignored env LANGUAGE
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_TYPE
debug3: Ignored env PANEL_GDK_CORE_DEVICE_EVENTS
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.utf8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT_PATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_CLASS
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env COLORFGBG
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env XDG_VTNR
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env _JAVA_OPTIONS
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Linux kali 5.5.0-kali2-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 5.5.17-1kali1 (2020-04-21) i686

The programs included with the Kali GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Kali GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
```

I am trying to do a WAN attack on my test PC. I don't have a router so I use this. I used NGROK before but it's domain port changed every time so I tried using this. Please Help Me.

I also used `sudo systemctl status ssh` and got:-

```
sudo systemctl status ssh
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-08-08 06:33:12 EDT; 11min ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
    Process: 2455 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2456 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4560)
     Memory: 4.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             └─2456 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups

Aug 08 06:33:18 kali sshd[2459]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=::1  user=root
Aug 08 06:33:20 kali sshd[2459]: Failed password for root from ::1 port 51100 ssh2
Aug 08 06:36:37 kali sshd[2522]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=::1  user=root
Aug 08 06:36:39 kali sshd[2522]: Failed password for root from ::1 port 51160 ssh2
Aug 08 06:38:02 kali sshd[2522]: Failed password for root from ::1 port 51160 ssh2
Aug 08 06:38:07 kali sshd[2522]: Failed password for root from ::1 port 51160 ssh2
Aug 08 06:38:07 kali sshd[2522]: Connection closed by authenticating user root ::1 port 51160 [preauth]
Aug 08 06:38:07 kali sshd[2522]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=::1  user=root
Aug 08 06:39:33 kali sshd[2546]: Accepted password for kali from ::1 port 51162 ssh2
Aug 08 06:39:33 kali sshd[2546]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user kali by (uid=0)
```

Thanks in Advance for Help.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what are you running on the localhost port 8080, I can't provide you exact answer.

The ssh connection seems to be all fine, so I guess that the problem is right in
the listener on your localhost.

You can try to debug the issue as following:

1. run `netcat -l -p 8080` on your machine.
2. Do the `ssh -R 80:localhost:8080 ssh.localhost.run`
3. Connect to the given url from your browser.

If you will see the HTTP request in the output of the netcat, the problem is in your listener (whatever it is). Based on my observation, the service currently works only for HTTP requests, thus trying to forward anything else might fail, even if theoretically it should work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your support. When I did as you said I got:-                           `root@kali:~# netcat -l -p 8080
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: root-732c2a71.localhost.run
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1`

Comment: After this again fail

Answer (score 0):

In the output just write 80 instead of 8080

```
ssh -R 80:localhost:80 ssh.localhost.run
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).